# Is this MVC pattern

Tags: java, model-view-controller

I developed project using JSP and servlets. The other techs are AJAX, jQuery, JavaScript, JSTL. I am not using any framework. Please let me know if it is in MVC Pattern I am not able to make out, If not I am ready to implement it in Spring. Will I need to rewrite the code for implementing it in spring?

I am not able to send image sorry as my reputation is low. Anyhow, will my application structure be in MVC? Just used jsp and servlets. Used netbeans IDE.

Comment: That isn't enough information to determine whether you've used MVC. Can you expand on the architecture.

Comment: Ya. I have created many jsp's in the WEB-INF folder and the neccessary java sources in Sources folder, When i look at spring implementation it look very lenghty actually I am thinking now what is it real use, many say we can reuse the code if MVC is implemented, But i can also reuse my just jsp and servlet written code, What is it's actual use, Why to follow such a lenghty process? Please ans those ques If you did not understand my architecture aslo, I feel there is something you guys understand and use frameworks, which I am not able to understand it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MVC represent Model, View and Controller. Your question doesn't provide much info about your current architecture but, it should be somewhat like below.

MVC mostly follow Separation between layers. This means all the component should be independent.

**Model** - Is your viewModel, Entity, POCO or simple DTO. No matter what you dig and get your data but Model should contain the data which you want to show on UI.

**View** - Is your View which can be anything (ASP, JSP, Silverlight or windows). View should be dumb as possible and just used to render the HTML.

**Controller** - Controller works like Ring Master of circus. Controller mediate  between view and Model, basically controller contains some methods(actions) which binds(or pass) Model to View.

See if you this is you architecture like.

Comment: No I miss controller, My model and view are directly connected. :d, From these many days I was thinking that model is my DB(mysql), jsp my view and servlets my controller. Is the so?

Comment: I am not JAVA guy, I think you need to search for more probably.

Comment: Any spring 3.1 and netbeans 7 guide?

Comment: http://netbeans.org/kb/docs/web/quickstart-webapps-spring.html might get you some direction